# C# ReadLine problem

Tags: c#, readline

what i want to do is that when people using my program hit enter without anything in there it does not cause an error here is part of the program:

```
Console.WriteLine("4.-Ya no quiero jugar >.<");
int opc = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

switch (opc)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("omg");
        break;

    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("wtf");
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Cant do that  >.>");
        Console.ReadKey();
        break;

    etc.
}
```

the thing is im using integers,i tried to do this

```
string opc1=console.readline();

if (opc =="")
{
    console.writeline("nope,try again");
}
else
{ // Brace was omitted in original - Jon
    int opc = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (opc)

    blah blah.
```

and different combinations of it >.< and default does not work for that

i hope some one can help me solve it >.<

Comment: to compare in Java I use the equals method, knowing nothing of c#, have you tried `if opc.equals("")`?

Comment: nope havent tried but if tryparse doesnt work im gonna try it tyvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Set your `Console.ReadLine()` to a variable.
Then check to see if the variable you set is not empty or null. Also, I'd recommend using the TryParse method of the Int16 class because it returns true or false depending on if the conversion was successful.

Also, you don't need to convert your `ReadLine` to an integer, because you can switch on Strings also. Since `ReadLine` is already a `String`, no conversion is necessary. However, if you need integers, try this:

```
String lineIn = Console.ReadLine();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lineIn))
{
    Int16 myNum;
    if (Int16.TryParse(lineIn , out myNum))
    {
            switch(myNum)
            {
                    case 1:
                    ...
                    default:
                    ...
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically you don't need any of the if statements in the example.  If you only execute Int16.TryParse(lineIn, out myNum); then you will end up with the integer the user entered as the value of myNum or 0 if the input was null, empty, a string or a number outside the min/max value of Int16.  The value of 0 would then be picked up by the default case.

Answer (score 10):

Check the `Int16.TryParse` method.

This will allow you to exit from the program or perform another action if the user input is not a number in the range allowed by `Int16` (negative 32768 through positive 32767).

Sample code can be found on MSDN entry ([Int16.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hh1awhy.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is int.Parse(...)

Answer (score 0):

you might look into using a [try catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw(VS.80).aspx) statement for error handling...

Answer (score 0):

TryParse:

```
string str;
short val;
while(!short.TryParse(str=Console.ReadLine(), out val))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cant do that  >.>");
}
```

Comment: Hi. If you want your code snippet to look pretty, try surrounding it in <pre><code> tags. <pre><code>my code</code></pre>. There is also a tool in the wysiwyg editor (the 101010 one). I only mention it because it took me a few tries to find it.

Answer (score 0):

For getting an integer i usually use a recursive function like this

```
private int GetInt()
{
     try
     {
         return int.parse(Console.Readline().Trim());
     } 
      catch (exception e) 
     {
         Console.WriteLine(string.format("{0} Please try again", e.message);
         return GetInt();
     }
}
```